# Mount error for luks image

Tags: luks

Everything works fine until I get the error:

```
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/img, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Summary:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen image.dd img
```

Enter passphrase for image.dd:

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/img /mnt
```

mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/img, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

Any idea what's causing this error? Have also tried manually mapping with losetup.

Thanks.

Comment: That's usually because the filesystem is damaged or there is none. Is the mapped device formatted? If so, you could try to correct errors with `fsck /dev/mapper/img`.

Comment: hmm,, fsck returns with fsck is in use...